# 502 Bad Gateway when using reverse proxy with Docker and Nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have searched StackOverflow for my problem but I always seem to be hitting the `502 Bad Gateway` with my Nginx Docker configuration. I am trying to access `pgadmin4` using my domain `mydomain.com/pgadmin` instead of `mydomain.com:8060` where `8060` is the port exposed by it's docker container. My `docker-compose.yml` file looks like this:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: nginx:1.19.6
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
        
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
        
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "8060:80"
      
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: defaultnetwork
```

The `default.conf` file of my nginx container looks like this:

```
upstream pgadmin {
    server 127.0.0.1:8060;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  mydomain.com;
    
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    
    location /pgadmin {
        proxy_pass http://pgadmin;
    } 
}
```

With this configuration, I keep getting the `502 Bad Gateway` error. Could someone kindly point to me where I am going wrong. I would really appreciate it.

Thanks.

[EDIT]
This is from the docker logs:

```
2021/02/03 08:07:42 [error] 23#23: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: ***.***.***.***, server: mydomain.com, request: "GET /pgadmin HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8082/pgadmin", host: "mydomain.com"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 502 problem comes from the loopback IP here:

> upstream pgadmin {
> server 127.0.0.1:8060;
> }

`127.0.0.1` or `localhost` for the NGINX container is the NGINX container itself. You should use the name of the service instead:

```
upstream pgadmin {
    server pgadmin:8060;
}
```

Name of the service comes from the `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
services:
  pgadmin: # <- this
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
```

If you hit 404 after these changes, this is because you have to change base path of the application. Try using this config:

```
    location /pgadmin/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /pgadmin;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://pgadmin;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @anemyte for this. I am one step closer. From the logs I can see that nginx correctly resolves the container's IP address. But the request looks like this: `GET /pgadmin HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.18.0.6:8082/pgadmin` instead of this: `GET /pgadmin HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.18.0.6:8082`. How can I fix this?

Comment: @realnsleo it works on port 80 by default, so you shouldn't specify port unless you've changed it in pgadmin config. That is just `proxy_pass http://pgadmin` as it was before.

Comment: Ah! Yes. Sorry. I have removed the ports from the `docker-compose.yml` file and I am now getting a 404 error. Any ideas?

Comment: @realnsleo I've managed to dig out a solution to it in web archive. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @anemyte thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Since your containers are working in the same network, you should access the Pgadmin container via 80th port from your Nginx container.

You should replace this line `server 127.0.0.1:8060` with `server pgadmin:80` in your Nginx config.